# How to transfer elements of one class to blocks of another class in js?

Tags: javascript

Please help me move several elements of the same class into the necessary blocks. There can be an unlimited number of blocks and elements. Elements contain different content. I would be glad for a hint both on pure js and jquery.

This is what the situation looks like initially:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="move-here">Move here 1
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>

  <div>Move from here 1
    <p class="moved-element"><b>Moved element 1</b></p>
    <p>p3</p>
    <p>p4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="move-here">Move here 2
    <p>p5</p>
    <p>p6</p>
  </div>

  <div>Move from here 2
    <p class="moved-element"><b>Moved element 2</b></p>
    <p>p7</p>
    <p>p8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the result should be like this:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="move-here">Move here 1
    <p class="moved-element"><b>Moved element 1</b></p>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>

  <div>Move from here 1

    <p>p3</p>
    <p>p4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="move-here">Move here 2
    <p class="moved-element"><b>Moved element 2</b></p>
    <p>p5</p>
    <p>p6</p>
  </div>

  <div>Move from here 2

    <p>p7</p>
    <p>p8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried this code:

```
const elementsToMove = document.querySelectorAll('.moved-element');
elementsToMove.forEach((element) => {
  const parent = element.parentNode;
  const target = document.querySelector('.move-here');
  target.insertBefore(element, target.firstChild);
});
```

Or:

```
const elementsToMove = document.querySelectorAll('.moved-element');
elementsToMove.forEach(element => {
  const targetBlock = element.closest('.move-here');
  if (targetBlock) {
    targetBlock.appendChild(element);
  }
});
```

Or:

```
$('.perenosimiy-element').appendTo('.perenesti-syuda');
```

None of this works as intended.

Link to a non-working example in the editor - https://codepen.io/YuriyFrolov/pen/PodMGyd

Comment: append adds the elements to the end of the parent. If you want to add them in the beginning, you want to use [`prepend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ancestor that .moved-element and .move-here have in common is .block, use closest to get the appropriate .block.

From .block use querySelector to find the appropriate .move-here.

.move-here has some text in it, we want .moved-element to appear after the text, so rather than inserting it before .move-here first child, we insert it before .move-here firstElementChild.

```js
const elementsToMove = document.querySelectorAll('.moved-element');
elementsToMove.forEach((element) => {
  const parent = element.closest(".block");
  const target = parent.querySelector('.move-here');
  target.insertBefore(element, target.firstElementChild);
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="move-here">Move here 1
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>

  <div>Move from here 1
    <p class="moved-element"><b>Moved element 1</b></p>
    <p>p3</p>
    <p>p4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="move-here">Move here 2
    <p>p5</p>
    <p>p6</p>
  </div>

  <div>Move from here 2
    <p class="moved-element"><b>Moved element 2</b></p>
    <p>p7</p>
    <p>p8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as it should.